# A Couple Obj-C Questions

Tags: objective-c

EDIT: My internet went out last night ._.

Well I'm new to the language. I got some basics down but:

1. `-(XYPoint *)origin`

   In this, why does the return value for this method look like a pointer? I'm confused. I know what void, id, double, etc are but I don't get why this has a pointer.
2. I was going through Kochans book, and I got to a program.

   ```
   myRect.origin = myPoint 

   NSLog(@"origin:(%i,%i)",myRect.origin.x,myRect.origin.y)
   ```

Or something like that.

But after the NsLog I put In a release. Then called the origin again, but it still got printed. Shouldn't it have gave an error?

Later, I printed another NSLog calling another variable, then after, I called the origin again, but this time I was given an error, though I was not when I tried calling it after the release. Sorry if this seems vague, but I will elaborate if needed.

Comment: And then there was a power failure in the OPs neighborhood...

Comment: If it is an Objective-C question, why isnt it tagged [objective-c]? Xcode is just an editor.

Comment: compilers don't like *Or something like that.* `[myRect.origin = myPoint]` is invalid code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Simply because the return type is a pointer type, so it's designated as returning a pointer.

   Note that anything can be turned into a pointer type where the pointer is returned rather than the object it points to in memory, but that's probably something more advanced than just Objective-C classes.
2. Release doesn't always mean the object gets deallocated right away. It can be instantaneous, or in a second, or a few, that it actually happens. Or, if the object was retained elsewhere, then it doesn't get deallocated yet at all.

Comment: The book I'm looking at doesn't explain why the return type is a pointer. I'm just rather confused. ._. Any way to make it more clearer please? And thanks for answering part 2!

Comment: @Jon Wei: If your method returns something that is an Objective-C class, you need to return a pointer, because when it comes to objects you are always handling pointers to objects in memory, rather than the objects themselves.

Comment: Hrmm, a little clearer, but my question is, why does it return a class specifically? Could it return just a plain integer? Sorry if I seem really new.

Comment: @Jon Wei: It can, but it depends entirely on the purpose of the integer that it returns. When you send an object a message, sometimes you expect it to return a result. That result can be anything, but most importantly it has to be something useful. If it's returning an instance of a class, then it just happens that it's something more complicated than a primitive type can do, I guess.